What is the reason for recovery code login failure?
So I started to implement 2FA for my .NET 8 application, but without razor pages. I also don't use cookies for authorization, I generate JWT tokens (this is just for context).
I managed to enable an authenticator for the user, to generate recovery codes (they are also stored in the database), and to login with a code from the authenticator app.
However, when I try to login with a recovery code:
signInManager.TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync(code); 

always returns "Failed". The code is a valid recovery code, I even tried to temporarily sign in the user right before, but this didn't help either.
[HttpPost("RecoveryCodeLogin")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RecoveryCodeLogin(RecoveryCodeLoginModel model)
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.UserEmail);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    var result = await signInManager.TwoFactorRecoveryCodeSignInAsync(model.RecoveryCode);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Ok(GenerateToken(user));
}

Any idea what is the reason for this and what can I do to fix it?

Cannot reproduce your issue. For the lacked details you could provide a minimal reproducible example. For this issue usually we start a default template to compare the differences between them and check the logs to find the errors. Based on my research on the source code and your description, it fails to redeem the recovery code. Have you tested the format issue var authenticatorCode = Input.TwoFactorCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty); ?
